# Compactness of the topology $\{U\subset \mathbb{Z} :\mathbb{Z}\setminus U\text{ is finite, or }0\notin U\}$ on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology

Is $\mathbb Z$ with the topology $$\tau=\{U\subset \mathbb{Z} :\mathbb{Z}\setminus U\text{ is finite, or }0\notin U\}$$ compact?

Comment: Hint: What is the complement of an open set containing $0$?

Comment: Ok now i got it